# Adding FTP Users via Simple Control Panel

Tags: centos, ftp, godaddy

I just got setup with CentOS yesterday through GoDaddy, and today I'm trying to get into the server and start setting up some of my projects. I'm able to get in through PuTTY just fine, but I'm not able to connect through FTP with the same (root) account.

I'm using Simple Control Panel, and have ensured that "Enable Server" is checked beneath
`System Configuration > FTP`. Further, I've checked, and double checked that my root password is correct when providing the FTP details.

Is there some other common setting I'm missing here that will prevent me from getting connected to the server to begin transfering files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't find any good documentation on Godaddy's Simple Control Panel. Maybe it is setup to use SFTP on port 22?

Comment: Wow, impressive. That seems to have done the job for me.